# nifi docker can not install sudo

Tags: linux, docker, apache-nifi

I have fired up a standalone NIFI docker container which is working fine.
And now I need to install sudo inside NIFI container but I get the permission denied.

To resolve the issue. I tried the below step

```
su -
apt-get install sudo -y
```

However when I am trying to become root it is asking for a password which I do not had.
I went through NIFI document but could not find any resolution.

Please suggest.

Comment: You shouldn't usually need `sudo` in Docker at all: you can install packages by switching to `USER root` in your Dockerfile, and you can `docker run -u root` to run a container as root if the Dockerfile defaults to something different.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks a lot this resolved my issue...i think i knew this but damn my slow mind..